# nmake compile error using QT 5.14.2 (MSCV 2017 64-bit) to build QWT-6.2.0

Tags: qt, qwt, msvc12

I am trying to install QWT-6.2.0(I tried QWT-6.1.4 also) on windows 11. I have installed QT-5.14.2 platform on my computer. I follow the guidance for windows on the webpage https://qwt.sourceforge.io/qwtinstall.html.

In QT command prompt, The command:

```
qmake qwt.pro
```

works well. However when i turned into next command:

```
nmake
```

It shows the errors like this:

```
qwt.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(214): error C2371: 'size_t': redefinition; different basic types
.\qwt.cpp: note: see declaration of 'size_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C3646: '__attribute__': unknown override specifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C2144: syntax error: '__int64' should be preceded by ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C3861: '__alignof__': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C3861: '__aligned__': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C2062: type '__int64' unexpected
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(426): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C3646: '__attribute__': unknown override specifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C2144: syntax error: 'long double' should be preceded by ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C3861: '__alignof__': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C3861: '__aligned__': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C2062: type 'long double' unexpected
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(427): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h(181): error C2371: 'ptrdiff_t': redefinition; different basic types
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h(145): note: see declaration of 'ptrdiff_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
```

These errors are just part of them. It seems that there are something wrong with the "stddef.h" file. This is a standart heat file for C and C++, which should have any errors in them.

I am a newbee on code. I don't know how to solve this.